# How can I redirect a particular file to be loaded from a remote server via Apache config?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want `http://mysite.com/somefile.html` to be loaded from a remote server via Apache. Is this possible in using `RewriteCond`'s?

Comment: Do you want to do a header redirect (= the client sees the remote server's address) or proxy the remote resource (= the client sees only your address)?

Comment: Client sees only my address, so I guess proxy the remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_rewrite provides the [P] flag, which allows URLs to be passed, via mod_proxy, to another server.

if you add this to your .htaccess file and customise for your specific situation it will work the way you describe.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /products/
RewriteRule    ^widget/(.*)$  http://product.example.com/widget/$1  [P]
ProxyPassReverse /products/widget/ http://product.example.com/widget/
```

Comment: The problem with this is that is straight up redirects the URL as well. Ideally, I don't want the URL to change, so it should continue to be http://mysite.com/products/widget/wahtever

Comment: The proxy approach as of my answer will just do that. @Shamoon

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use `mod_proxy` for this instead of rewriting:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyRequests Off

  <proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </proxy>

  ProxyPass /somefile.html http://remote.example.com/somefile.html
  ProxyPassReverse /somefile.html http://remote.example.com/somefile.html
</IfModule>
```